# Android doesn't kill bound service

Tags: android

I am creating bound service for socket connection.Which means it is creating a long polling connection and listens my server.If user closes the app in task manager my service is killing i have no problem with this.But when user presses the back button I am calling `activity.finish()` method for close app.But with this method my service doesn't kill,it is still connected to socket server.

Is this normal ? And Could be this drain the battery ?

My service:

```
public class SocketService extends Service {
    //you need constants to tell servise and activity what you are sending a message for
    public static final int REGISTER_CHAT_ACTIVITY = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 2;

    final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());
    Messenger chat;
    private Socket socket;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("ip");

            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                }
            }).on("connected", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {

                }
            }).on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                try {
                    chat.send(android.os.Message.obtain(null, MESSAGE_RECEIVED, args[0]));
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        });
            //and add all the other on listeners here
            socket.connect();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.disconnect();
            socket.connect();
        } else {
            try {
                socket = IO.socket("ip");
                socket.connect();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mMessenger.getBinder();
    }
    class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what){
                case REGISTER_CHAT_ACTIVITY:
                      chat = msg.replyTo;
                      break;
            }
        }
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        SocketService getService() {
            return SocketService.this;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: do you want kill the service when activity finished?

Comment: Actually,yes i want to kill

Comment: add this in your manifest android:stopWithTask="true"

Comment: nothing changed it is same

Comment: hmmm, could you provide some code of this service? i mean overrided methods(there is no need to full code, only names of the methods that you override) and more important loop with the socket calls ... I'm pretty sure that you do not break the loop on "some kind of unbind"

Comment: ok ... did you try to disconnect the socket in overrided unBind?

Comment: yes,it is still continue to working.I think thread is not killing.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar a while ago i solved the issue by using shared preferences.(Note: I dont think it's the best answer but it solved my problem)

I saved in preferences a boolean to register when i dont need the service anymore but lost reference of it.

```
public class YourService extends Service {
    private YourService serv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        serv = this;
```

Then Somehwere on your code that the service does frequently.

```
    if(!sharedPref.getBoolean("TurnOffService", false)){
            serv.stopSelf();

    }
```

Hope it helps.